# AxiosError: Request failed with status code 404

Tags: react-native, axios, http-status-code-404, http-delete

Here the delete function

```
  const DeletePost = (id) => {

console.log(id);
axios.delete(`${BASE_URL}/futureevents/delete/${id}`)
  .then(res => {
    console.log("success");
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  })
```

}

console log display id ,but ID not going to backend. When I use postmen, then work properly.
what is the error in above function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

error is `/` .
not need `/` after `${BASE_URL}`
because end of my BASE_URL already have `/` .

```
BASE_URL = "http://192.168.204.74:3000/api/v1/"
```

before fixed

```
axios.delete(`${BASE_URL}/futureevents/delete/${id}`)
```

after fixed

```
axios.delete(`${BASE_URL}futureevents/delete/${id}`)
```